# Curvature of a Planar Graph

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curvature

a) Show that the curvature of the planar graph *r* = *f*($\theta$) at a general point  is

$\kappa(\theta)$ = $\frac{[2f'^2(\theta) + f^2(\theta) - f(\theta)f''(\theta)]}{[(f'^2(\theta) + f^2(\theta))^{3/2}]}$

b) Find the curvature of the curve *r* = *a*(1 - cos $\theta$).

I have been looking in my textbook for a solution to this problem and I have not come across anything too helpful.  I have seen this formula in my book but nothing providing me with a gateway to finding a solution.  Any help would be much appreciated on a) and/or b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess your curvature formula is 
$$\kappa = \frac{\|{\bf r}'(t)\times{\bf r}''(t)\|}{\|{\bf r}'(t)\|^3}
$$

There are several and this should work.
First note to go from polar to cartesian we have
$${\bf r}(t) = \langle r\cos(t),r\sin(t) \rangle
$$

So for you 
$${\bf r}(t) = \langle f(t)\cos(t),f(t)\sin(t),0 \rangle
$$

Now just compute ${\bf r}'(t)$ and ${\bf r}''(t)$ (you'll need the 
product rule).  It goes something like
$${\bf r}'(t) = \langle f'(t)\cos(t) + f(t)(-\sin(t)), \ldots \rangle
$$

In part (b) just apply the formula from part (a).

So you have all these pieces above like $f(\theta)$ and $f'(\theta)$.  These
pieces are

$$f(\theta) = a(1 - \cos(\theta))$$
and 
$$f'(\theta) = a\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful! One small question though, maybe it's just my understanding or a typo, but in your first coordinate of **r**(t), where you're demonstrating the beginning of the product rule, shouldn't it be $...+ f(t)(-sin(t)),...$? That second f(t) shouldn't have its derivative right? If I'm remembering the product rule correctly that is.

Comment: Thank you.  You are right and I fixed that typo.